# d3 snap brush to dates on xAxis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following data display on a d3 chart:

```
[{
    "Date": "2012",
    "Total": 5340
}, {
    "Date": "2013",
    "Total": 4120
}, {
    "Date": "2014",
    "Total": 1259
}, {
    "Date": "2015",
    "Total": 3617
}, {
    "Date": "2016",
    "Total": 2005
}]
```

The chart also has a brush on it so the user can focus on a selection of years by dragging the brush. However the brush allows the user to drag across all dates between the first and last year.

What I want to do is make it snap to the years as the user is brushing.

Here is my code for the brush events:

```
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(xScale2)
    .on('brush', brushed);

function brushed() {
    var min = d3.min(data.map(function (d) {
        return d.total;
    }));
    var max = d3.max(data.map(function (d) {
        return d.total;
    }));
    var extent = brush.extent();
    if (!brush.empty()) {

        // Snap to years
            var newBrush = extent.map(d3.time.year.round);
            if (newBrush[0] >= newBrush[1]) {// If empty when rounded, use floor & ceil instead.
                newBrush[0] = d3.time.year.floor(extent[0]);
                newBrush[1] = d3.time.year.ceil(extent[1]);

            }
            // update the extent
            brush.extent([newBrush[0], newBrush[1]]);
            extent = brush.extent();

            xScale.domain(brush.empty() ? xScale2.domain() : extent);
            yScale.domain([
                d3.min(data.map(function (d) {
                    return (d.date >= extent[0] && d.date <= extent[1]) ? d.total : max;
                })),
                d3.max(data.map(function (d) {
                    return (d.date >= extent[0] && d.date <= extent[1]) ? d.total : min;
                }))
            ]);

        xScale.domain(brush.empty() ? xScale2.domain() : extent);
        yScale.domain([
            d3.min(data.map(function (d) {
                return (d.date >= extent[0] && d.date <= extent[1]) ? d.total : max;
            })),
            d3.max(data.map(function (d) {
                return (d.date >= extent[0] && d.date <= extent[1]) ? d.total : min;
            }))
        ]);
    }
    totalChart.attr('d', totalLine); // update line
    focus.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis); // update xAxis
    focus.select('.y.axis').call(yAxis); // update yAxis
}
```

This is based on: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6232620

So the idea is that the year is rounded off first and then the extent is modified before being applied to the domains and should be making the brush snap... however it doesn't snap... instead it makes the user fight to drag it between the years. I want to it to actually snap to the next year when the user starts dragging. They should never be able to drag in between the years.

Comment: You just want it to work yearly or you want it to be rounded to dates present in data?

Comment: @SaeedAdelMehraban Just yearly in this example and then once it snaps properly I can adapt it to work for my other date formats. So in short snap to the years.

Comment: I have updated my answer to work with d3 v3.

Comment: @SaeedAdelMehraban I noticed you used brushend when doing v3... Is this because you can't get the snap working in realtime with v3 like you can with v4?

Comment: join me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122833/discussion-between-saeed-adel-mehraban-and-cameron)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's mbostock code with year snapping. It just has a little bug for background bounds.

This code works fine except for a little flaw in background/brush element sync.

```js
var margin = {top: 0, right: 40, bottom: 50, left: 40},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(2012, 1, 1), new Date(2023, 1, 1)])
    .range([0, width]);
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x)
    .extent([new Date(2014, 1, 1), new Date(2015, 1, 1)])
    .on("brushend", brushended);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "grid-background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(d3.time.months, 6)
        .tickSize(-height)
        .tickFormat(""))
  .selectAll(".tick")
    .classed("minor", function(d) { return d.getHours(); });
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(d3.time.years)
      .tickPadding(0))
  .selectAll("text")
    .attr("x", 6)
    .style("text-anchor", null);
var gBrush = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.event);
gBrush.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("height", height);
function brushended() {
  if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return; // only transition after input
  var extent0 = brush.extent(),
      extent1 = extent0.map(d3.time.year.round);
  // if empty when rounded, use floor & ceil instead
  if (extent1[0] >= extent1[1]) {
    extent1[0] = d3.time.year.floor(extent0[0]);
    extent1[1] = d3.time.year.ceil(extent0[1]);
  }
  d3.select(this).transition()
      .call(brush.extent(extent1))
      .call(brush.event);
}
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 11px sans-serif;
}
.axis path {
  display: none;
}
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid-background {
  fill: #ddd;
}
.grid line,
.grid path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid .minor.tick line {
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}
.brush .extent {
  stroke: #000;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>

<body>
</body>
```

Comment: Is brush.move a new feature in 4.0 of d3?

Comment: @Cameron As you can see d3 version in this sample code is v4. You can see the difference between v3 and v4 brushes [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: What does `brush.move` do that `brush.extent` doesn't? As you can see in my example I update the values in `brush.extent` to try and make it snap. As I'm using d3.v3 which doesn't have `brush.move`. Thanks.

Comment: @Cameron brush extent in v4 is used to set overall brushable area and brushes don't save current selection internally.

Comment: So is it not possible to do snapping in v3?

Comment: @Cameron I will update my answer with v3 code and inform you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122833/discussion-between-saeed-adel-mehraban-and-cameron).